# Populate dynamic array with unknown # of Strings

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dynamic-arrays

Many apologies if this has been answered, but I have been unable to find an answer here, or Google for that matter. I'm using Excel, so I will be referencing columns/rows.

I need to create a cost analysis table with a couple conditions like:

1. What is the Category? (Full list: Fruits, Vegetables, Meats)
2. What Supplier was the item purchased from? (i.e. Sobey's, Walmart, etc.)

So I have:

```
Dim catFruits() as string, catVegies() as string, catMeats() as string
```

to declare arrays for each category. I have it going down the "Category" column by each row and checking the category to select the correct array. What I want it to do next is go down the "Supplier" column by row and add the contents of the cell to the selected array, but not if the Supplier is already in the array. I have not been able to find a way to do this. What I have so far:

```
For x = 1 To lastRow
    If Sheet1.Cells(x, catCol).Text = "Fruits" Then
        catFruits() = Array(Sheet1.Cells(x, supCol).Text)
        '|----------what I want to do----------|
        catFruits() = Array(catFruits(), Sheet1.Cells(x,SupCol).Text)
        'so it's like "x = x + 1"
        '|-----but in a way that will work-----|
        '|----------and without dupes----------|
    ElseIf Sheet1.Cells(x, catCol).Text = "Vegetables" Then
        catVegies() = Array(Sheet1.Cells(x, supCol).Text)
    ElseIf Sheet1.Cells(x, catCol).Text = "Meats" Then
        catMeats() = Array(Sheet1.Cells(x, supCol).Text)
    End If
Next x
```

I can figure out the duplicate part myself, just another loop and if would solve that.

Rest assured that all variables I'm using have been declared properly (except maybe the arrays, I'm not familiar with working with them), and am using Option Explicit.

If you need any other information, just ask, I'll help where I can.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless there is a reason not to use a dictionary you could use a `Dictionary` object to do this. It is easier to work with, has these functions built in, and is overall a little cleaner.

With this you should end up with an object which contains a unique list of items for each of your categories.

**Edit:** I made the key be the item and the value be the number of occurrences of that item.

**Edit Again:** As per Tim Williams suggestion, I made this a dictionary of dictionaries. This means you'll only need to manage the uniqueness logic once.

```
'AllCategories dictionary will be used to hold the text string unique to a cetegory
'(eg. "Fruits") as the key and the value will be a dictionary used to hold all the
'unique values and their count within that category
Dim AllCategories As Dictionary
Set AllCategories = New Dictionary
'category dictionaries
Dim catFruits As Dictionary, catVegies As Dictionary, catMeats As Dictionary
Set catFruits = New Dictionary 'if the Microsoft Scripting Runtime Reference is checked
Set catVegies = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")  'if the MSR reference is NOT checked
Set catMeats = New Dictionary
'link all the category dictionaries to the AllCategories dictionary 
AllCategories.Add "Fruits", catFruits
AllCategories.Add "Vegetables", catVegies
AllCategories.Add "Meats", catMeats
'add more categories to the AllCategories dictionary here as needed

Dim categoryText As String, supColValue As String
For X = 1 To lastRow
    categoryText = Sheet1.Cells(X, catCol).text
    If AllCategories.Exists(categoryText) Then
        AllCategories (categoryText)
        supColValue = Sheet1.Cells(X, supCol).text
        If Not AllCategories(categoryText).Exists(supColValue) Then
            catFruits.Add supColValue, 1    'establish first entry of this supColValue and set count to 1
        Else
            catFruits(supColValue) = catFruits(supColValue) + 1 'increment the count of this supColValue by one
        End If
    Else
        'the value in Sheet1.Cells(X, catCol).text did not correspond to an established category
    End If
Next X
```

You need to ensure you have a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime `(Tools>References>Microsoft Scripting Runtime> check the box> OK)`. You can use referenced objects like the dictionary in a way described by martin in the comments. There are advantages to this. I like adding the reference though so you get the Intellisense text on your objects. That way you don't need to know all the methods by heart.

Comment: You can create Dictionary without adding reference, just declare it as an Object and then use `CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")`. You can also use the dictionary to actually count the number of occurrences of each supplier, that might come handy later.

Comment: Even better - a Dictionary of dictionaries: no need to change your code when you add new categories...

Comment: Very true. All good ideas! :). I modified for @martin's comments so far.

Comment: @TimWilliams I might have modified my answer to do a dictionary of dictionaries not how you were intending. I was thinking the OP would want control over the literals used to designate each dictionary but maybe they just want each unique string to be a new dictionary (i.e. it's more dynamic-less control over what's included/ less dynamic-more control over category inclusion). That's up to them I guess.

Comment: This is fantastic, thanks everyone for pitching in! Not sure which I will use yet (tipping into Dictionary's favour), but definitely will read on on these, they seem like they'd be immensely helpful!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ReDim Preserve` to make room for new element. There is however no built-in function to verify if an item is already in in the array, you will have to write one yourself, for example like this:

```
Function ItemPresent(myArray() As string, item As string) As Boolean

Dim v As Variant
For Each v In myArray
    If v = item Then
        ItemPresent = True
        Exit Function
    End If
Next
ItemPresent = False

End Function
```

Then in your main function, you will code like this:

```
Option Base 0 'this is very important, it tells VBA the arrays are 0 indexed

...

Dim nCatFruits As Integer, nCatVegies As Integer, nCatMeats As Integer
nCatFruits = 0
nCatVegies = 0
nCatMeats = 0

...

ReDim Preserve catFruits(0 To nCatFruits)
nCatFruits = nCatFruits + 1
catFruits(nCatFruits - 1) = s 's contains the text you want to add to array
```

Comment: I've read about using ReDim Preserve, but I heard that it was a performace killer, and wasn't efficient. I thought there was also a way to have an array that you could dynamically add to... I guess I was led astray... Thanks though!

Comment: @Daevin - you don't necessarily have to `ReDim Preserve` for each new item; you could `ReDim Preserve` in blocks of say 100, 1000 etc and manage occurances of Empty items in  the array.

Comment: There are 'arrays' you can dynamically add to. They are called `Collection` objects. And a variant on them is the `Dictionary` object. Collections are sorted while Dictionaries have Key/Value pairs to keep them organized. Both have very nice methods for accessing entries.

Comment: You can ReDim array in larger increments if you are concerned about performance. Or you can use dictionaries, as Brad suggests, that's a very good idea.